# Difficulty with function not behaving properly when multiple button groups are on same page

Tags: jquery, click, slidetoggle

I'm currently working on my portfolio and I'm stuck trying to solve this problem. I have certain amount of work that I'm going to display within my portfolio. When the user clicks on a project img it reveals the project details, underneath there is a group of 3 buttons. Those buttons reveal more images relating to the project. I ended up getting the buttons to work and reveal the content, but I'm running into a problem. That when I have more than one project opened it effects both group of buttons!

Also, I noticed when you click on the button the page jumps to the top of the section

Here's an example... 
http://jsfiddle.net/63x7v/3/

```
$(".button").click(function () {
 $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
 var myelement = $(this).attr("href");
 $(myelement).slideToggle(600, "swing");
 $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
});
```

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6WBmH/1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each `section` is a project, you can target only the elements within it

```
$(".button").click(function (e) {
    //prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var myelement = $(this).attr("href");
    $(myelement).slideToggle(600, "swing");
    //find the toggle elements within current project(section) only
    $(this).closest('section').find(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6WBmH/)